# strongswan ikev2 cisco traffic selectors inacceptable

Tags: cisco, strongswan

Trying to connect StrongSwan to a Cisco ASA (not mine) But I get traffic selectors inacceptable

In the following logs Shouldn't 172.17.100.198/32 be a public ip address?

```
looking for a child config for 10.1.3.254/32 10.1.3.0/24 === 172.17.100.198/32 172.17.100.0/24
Dec 12 00:19:25 10-146-37-254 charon: 14[CFG] proposing traffic selectors for us:
Dec 12 00:19:25 10-146-37-254 charon: 14[CFG] 10.1.3.0/24
Dec 12 00:19:25 10-146-37-254 charon: 14[CFG] proposing traffic selectors for other:
Dec 12 00:19:25 10-146-37-254 charon: 14[CFG] 172.17.100.0/24
Dec 12 00:19:25 10-146-37-254 charon: 14[IKE] traffic selectors 10.1.7.254/32 10.146.37.0/24 === 172.17.100.198/32 172.17.100.0/24 inacceptable
```

Relevant config

```
leftid=my_internal
leftsubnet=10.1.7.0
rightsubnet=172.17.100.0/24
rightid=their_external
```

Comment: There seems to be a confusion regarding 10.1.3.0/24 vs. 10.1.7.0/24.

Answer (score 1):

This has been solved, it was a mismatch of subnets.